# Connection between quivers and representations of Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, quiver

Can anyone recommend a reference to study the connection between quiver theory and representation theory of Lie algebras?

Supposedly those two things have something to do with each other, with the notion of *root system* appearing in different places. However I apart from bearing the same name, I'm not sure what those definitions have to do with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gabriel's theorem is the one involving finite root systems in the representation theory of quivers.  It basically says that a connected quiver admits finitely many indecomposable representations if and only if it is an orientation of a Dynkin diagram of type ADE, and gives a bijection between the set of indecomposable representations and the set of positive roots of the associated root system.

As for references, I recommend Gelfand, Berenstein and Ponomarev's paper *Coxeter functors and Gabriel's theorem* for a nice proof of the theorem.  Of course, there are more modern texts giving an account of the theorem, for instance Assem, Simson and Skowroński's book *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras I Techniques of Representation Theory*.

From there, there are many other links between Lie algebras and representation theory of quivers.  I will just mention a theorem of Ringel, realizing the quantum enveloping algebra of the positive part of a Lie algebra as the Ringel-Hall algebra of the associated quiver.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. This seems a bit too advanced for me already though, as I am stillt puzzled what is the connection between "root system of a quiver with Dynkin diagram" and "root system for a Lie algebra".

It's probably not very difficult to see, but for someone self-studying both topics it is difficult for me to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

There is another fascinating connection between ADE shaped quivers and an root systems of Lie algebras, namely the so-called geometric McKay correspondence.
If you define the moduli space of representations of a Dynkin quiver with pre-projective relations, and quotient it (after throwing away "bad" points first) by the product of $GL_n$ groups acting via base change on each node, then you actually get a variety. This variety will be the Klein singularity associated with the ADE root system in question.

For example, take the quiver shaped like an $A_n$ Dynkin diagram, whereby links between nodes correspond to pairs of arrows, one going each way. Supplement this quiver with appropriate quadratic pre-projective relations. Now, the appropriately built moduli space of representations with dimension vector $d=(1,1,1, ..., 1)$ will actually be the $A_n$ singularity.
By deforming the stability condition you use in order to make the GIT quotient, you will see a resolved singularity, with a chain of $P^1$'s connected in the shape of the $A_n$ Dynkin diagram.

Pretty cool stuff.